# RequestPermissions deprecated in Java

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-permissions

I have a function that I call in a fragment that opens an an AlertDialog and asks to take a picture or take a picture from the phone
.
Before calling the two individual functions presentFiles() or presentCamera() I check the permissions with requestPermissions.

everything worked fine, but I upgraded though the sdk version to 34 and besides having requestPermissions which is obsolete (but that was before too) the window to ask the user for permissions to take a picture or access files from the phone no longer opens.

Can you help me to correct the problem

Below I will paste my entire function.

Thank you

```
    fun displayPicker() {

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity)
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.label_add_file))

    builder.setTitle("")
        .setItems(
            arrayOf("Choisir un fichier", "Prendre une photo")
        ) { _, which ->
            if (which == 0) {
                if (requireContext().checkSelfPermission(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(
                        arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_FILES
                    )
                } else {
                    presentFiles()
                }


            } else if (which == 1) {

                if (requireContext().checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(
                        arrayOf(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA
                    )
                } else {
                    presentCamera()
                }

            }
        }

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel) { _, _ ->

    }
    builder.show()
}

   override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
  ) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA && permissions.contains(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && grantResults.first() == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        presentCamera()
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_FILES && permissions.contains(
            READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) && grantResults.first() == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        presentFiles()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the AlertDialog isn't showing?

Comment: @Noamaw Yes I do not display the permission question from version 33 onwards

Comment: Is the alert dialog (that asks if to take picture with camera, or open file explorer) not been displayed? or is the permission request after the user clicks on their choice?

Answer (score 0):

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are not being used after Android 13 if you'll use it with `checkSelfPermission` it will always return FALSE, update your permission array with new permission READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, Add the same in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

var permissionNew = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    )

   private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
    var result: Int
    val listPermissionsNeeded: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    for (p in permissionNew) {
        result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, p)
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(p)
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toTypedArray(), 200)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

In case you have to write files just make sure you're using app's file directory.